# Add tag referencing to Editing Help page

Tags: feature-request, markdown, help

I've seen questions that have properly-styled links to tags on their respective SE site (see [this question](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/tag-wikis-tags-that-need-clarification) for an example), but I have no idea how to do this myself.

Should these instructions be added to the [editing help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) template for SE sites?